# What is the actual type of the variable "t" in a GoLang Type Switch?

Tags: types, go, type-switch

Given:

```
type MyInterface interface{

    MyMethod() int

}

var im MyInterface
...
```

If I call:

```
switch t := im.(type) {

   case:....

   default:...

}
```

What is the actual **type** of the variable `t` when it is declared? To illustrate the question: If I wanted to write

```
var t //What type should I use?!
```

How would I declare `t` ?

For example In Delphi we have this structure:

```
TTypeInfo = record
  Kind: TTypeKind;
  Name: string;
  {TypeData: TTypeData}
end;
```

I believe I am looking for something in GoLang that is akin to `TTypeKind`, which has potential values such as `tkInteger`, `tkString` etc.

In C++, we find the `type_info` class type, which also provides some of this functionality.

What type would I use for `t` in the `var t...` declaration? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type switch in Go is weird and special business. It’s not a generalization of another form that happens to be applied to types.

To my knowledge, you can’t write it using `var` (and I do recognize that you only mention the `var` form as illustration).

Within a `case` clause of the switch, `t` has the type *specified in that case* (see @Mue’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21934207/70613)). Inside the `default` clause, it has `im`’s original type.

To answer your question, the `t` symbol in this case is weird and special, and only meaningful in the context of the switch. Its type is context-dependent. I hesitate to even call it a variable.

Edit, speculation:

I haven’t looked at the compiler but I suspect it deconstructs each `case` into a type assertion (cast), the result of which is a local variable within the scope of the `case` clause. As a syntactic convenience, you can refer to each using the `t` symbol.

Comment: _The type switch in Go is weird and special business... I hesitate to even call it a variable_ From everything I have culled thus far, so it appears: It's a special construct that can only be used in that particular way.

Answer (score 3):

In the following line:

```
switch t := im.(type) {
```

`t` is already declared & initialized with the value of the type, therefore you don't have to declare it again using `var t`.

Comment: Did not answer the question... I didn't ask **if** it was necessary. Let's say I found a use for declaring it that way, the question is **how** to do it? Is your point that `t` has no type except when assigned a type based on the value it receives when using auto: `t:=` ? i.e. - the declaration and assignment **cannot** be separated?

Answer (score 2):

It is simple and needs no declaring.

```
switch t := anyVar.(type) {
case ThisType:
    // t is of type ThisType
case ThatType:
    // t is of type ThatType
default:
    // t has its original type.
}
```

And by the way, please no prefix I for an interface, that's no Go style. Typically you choose a subject matching to the verb(s) of the method(s). See

```
type Writer interface {
    Write([]byte) (int, error)
}
```

Comment: See comment on @Agis's answer - same applies to yours.